# Using generic types in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I have a hard time to figure out, how I can implement seemingly easy patterns with the strict typing system that C#'s generic system is restricted to. Coming from a mostly Java background, I am used to wildcards for generic types. Since C# does not allow such things I need your help to figure out the most elegant way to implement the following (my implementation is for a Unity3D project but that's really not important I think):

I have *Content Providers* that can provide various types of content (s.a. objects of the type "Texture", "String",...)
Therefore I created an abstract generic class and an interface such that my architecture look like this

[image: Architecture of interface, abstract class and concrete classes that implement it]

Furthermore I have *Content Receivers* that are able to handle the content of a certain type and a managing class with a set of such *Content Receivers*. I want the logic for what receiver has to deal with the content of a given provider in a style something like this:

```
public void accept(IUIContentProvider provider){
    //1. Check if a receiver for the generic type of the provider exists
    
    //2. Ignore the call if no such receiver exists, otherwise pass the provider to this class and 
    //let it deal with it in some specific manner.
}
```

But due to the strong type system of C# it seems to be impossible to do anything elegant using Polymorphism. I also can not explicitly convert the IUIContentProvider apparently. I can not even use an abstract base method like:

```
public abstract object provideContent()
```

and to override it with e.g.:

```
public override Texture provideContent(){...}
```

At this point I start to wonder if it is even wise to use generics for this purpose in C#...

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to demonstrate a problem. Post what you have written so far and what parts of it aren't working, then maybe we can help.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do? I also think the type system is as strict as in java if my memory is good...

Comment: If your `UIContentProvider<T>` is generic .. why don't you simply make also the `IUIContentProvider` a generic? And then your content receivers can also be generic and accept/expect the same content type

Answer (score 2):

You said in your abstract/generic class `UIContentProvider<T>` you wanted to have such method :

```
public abstract object ProvideContent();
```

And you want to be able to have this override in your concrete implementation `TextProvider` :

```
public override string ProvideContent(){...};
```

But I think you miss the point of the generic in your abstract class... What is the point of having a type parameter T if you don't use it?

Isn't it what you want ?

```
public interface IUIContentProvider<T>
{
    T ProvideContent();
}

public abstract class UIContentProvider<T> : IUIContentProvider<T>
{
    public abstract T ProvideContent();
}


public class TextProvider : UIContentProvider<string>
{
    public override string ProvideContent()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```